# Make subplot square in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, subplot

I have put 3 graphs in one line, how to make them all square

I use a for-loop for subplot

```
for iter = 1:3
     subplot(1,3,iter)
end
```

Could anyone just give me some simple sample code, I could copy?

Comment: does `axis square` work?

Comment: I have searched this command, but sorry for my poor programming skills, I still do not understand how to use that command..

Answer (score 3):

You can use `axis square`. As soon as you plot/show something, you can type that command and axis will adjust itself. I am giving two code samples, you can see the difference for yourself:

```
%--------  Without 'axis square'  --------
figure(1);
for iter = 1:3
   subplot(1,3,iter);
   imshow('peppers.png');
end

%--------  With 'axis square'  --------
figure(2);
for iter = 1:3
   subplot(1,3,iter);
   imshow('peppers.png');
   axis square;
end
```

There are other commands like `axis ij`, `axis xy` etc. You can try them out to see what happens. You can find all the commands [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axis.html).

Comment: The plot becomes very contorted when doing so, producing lots of whitespace. What should happen, is that the figure width is adapted to the number of horizontal subplots. However, MATLAB does not do this automatically.